# How can we train OneVsRestClassifier with the output of FastText

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, fasttext

Can we train OneVsRestClassifier with the output of FastText as shown below:

**GENSIM Library with FastText**

```
fasttext_out=model_ted.wv.most_similar("The Lemon Drop Kid , a New York City swindler, is illegally touting horses at a Florida racetrack. After several successful hustles, the Kid comes across a beautiful, but gullible, woman intending to bet a lot of money. The Kid convinces her to switch her bet, employing a prefabricated con. Unfortunately for the Kid, the woman belongs to notorious gangster Moose Moran , as does the money.")

print(fasttext_out)
```

**Output:**

```
[('Foreign legion', 0.9770169258117676), ('Kafkaesque', 0.9751489162445068), ('Reboot', 0.9710761308670044), ('Space opera', 0.9696193337440491), ('Outlaw', 0.9682430028915405), ('Libraries and librarians', 0.9682008028030396), ('Parkour in popular culture', 0.9671787619590759), ('Movies About Gladiators', 0.963977575302124), ('Baseball', 0.9581758379936218), ('Cyberpunk', 0.9565480351448059)]
```

**Using Logistic Regression, which is a binary classification algorithm and use it with the One-vs-Rest heuristic to perform multi-class classification**

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(lr)

// xtrain_tfidf, ytrain are the outputs of TF-IDF and I want to give outputs of FastText
clf.fit(xtrain_tfidf, ytrain)
```

Apologies about this question and I am not sure if it is possible or not but I am just curious If I can train OneVsRestClassifier with the output of FastText since I can train OneVsRestClassifier with the output of TF-IDF but I am unable to find anything similar to my question on the internet.

Can someone please confirm if it is possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Gensim `.most_similar()` method, in the form you're using, expects a **single word**, not a full string sentence.

But, the `FastText` model vectors can take any word, even one that's out-of-vocabulary ("OOV") compared to tis training data, and synthesize a guess vector for it.

By providing it that long string, `"The Lemon Drop Kid , a New York City swindler, is illegally touting horses at a Florida racetrack. After several successful hustles, the Kid comes across a beautiful, but gullible, woman intending to bet a lot of money. The Kid convinces her to switch her bet, employing a prefabricated con. Unfortunately for the Kid, the woman belongs to notorious gangster Moose Moran , as does the money."`, you've asked it to synthesize a word-vector for a 391-letter word – where some of the 'letters' are spaces and punctuation. And then, to report other known, in-vocabulary words that are close to that vector.

So, it'll calculate such a vector as requested, but it's probably not very good! And the list of nearest-neighbors to that vector, as returned by `.most_similar()`, aren't what you'd need for a downstream classifier.

`FastText` inherently only gives you word-vectors: a vector per word. If you want a vector for a longer run of text, like a lot of words, you'll need to make more decisions about how you want to turn a bunch of individual word-vectors into something else.

It's an OK decision to simply try: averaging all those words together. (There are many other ways to represent larger texts as vectors, or bags-of-other-values.)

You could then try passing those averages as the features to a downstream classifier.

The FastText `-supervised` mode, available in the [original FaceBook FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) but not Gensim, is a way to combine FastText training and a simple classifier at the same time, with the word-vector optimized for how well they help the classifier, under this same sort of "Average all the words together" combination. You may want to try that, too, though it may be harder to customize in Python.